# Executing C program in BASH with 2 arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I have a C program executable which required two arguments. The first argument is a **abc.dat** file and the second argument is **abc.csv** file. The program inputs the **.dat** file and converts it to a **.csv** file. The **.dat** exists when running the program and it creates the **.csv** which was the second argument.

I am trying to convert all the files in a folder using a bash script.

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in /home/labadmin/Desktop/6122017/1252017
do
    ./my_read_bfee *.dat *.csv
done
```

When I execute the bash script I get:

```
usage: read_bfee in.dat out.csv
```

Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you wanted

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in /home/labadmin/Desktop/6122017/1252017/*.dat
do
    ./my_read_bfee "$file" "${file%.dat}.csv"
done
```

otherwise the `*.dat` inside the for loop is expanded to all files matching in current directory for each iteration